# how to use mongoose $near? (type data location)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have field location array for coordinates

```
{
  location: [13.3339, 80.1943],
  ...someOtherfield
}
```

can I use $near in mongoose with that data? specifically in mongoose **aggregate**?
or I must change data field like this

```
{
  location: {
    type: { type: 'Point' },
    coordinates: [13.3339, 80.1943],
   },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document implies that you are storing location using `Legacy Coordinate Pairs`

```
location: [<longitude>, <latitude> ]
```

Yes, you can use **$near** with your data, if you have **2d index,** on your location field. [2d index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/)

After that, You can query like this

```
db.collection.find(
   { location : { $near : [ -73.9667, 40.78 ], $maxDistance: 0.10 } }
)
```

You can refer it from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)

Comment: sure it work, can I use in aggregate? cause I didn't find it in the documentation

Comment: You can refer this link, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Comment: oh i see, what you say about "Legacy Coordinate Pairs", thanks @namar,

Comment: hallo @namar, my last question, what is the unit of response distance? i got value 0.009097714273377067 from on of data,
if I check on maps the distance around 1KM

Comment: if you use legacy coordinate pairs the the `$maxDistance` is specified in radians and if you use geoJson object then `$maxDistance` is in metres.

You can refer from here for the conversions https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/

Comment: If I was you, I would be using geoJSON objects (2d sphere index), as they give more accurate results than legacy coordinate pairs

Comment: Hi @ArifFathurrohman if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: ok im understand now, thanks for helping me @namar sood